# Is there any semantic difference between grant and access?

Tags: database-design, semantics

Naming logic and can't decide. Grant or access...

- Is one closer tied to accounts?
- One closer to restrictions based on realtime calcuations?
- Other considerations.

Indians, natives: Please speak.

Comment: And there's permission too..

Comment: In practical terms it depends entirely on what database you are referring to. Access/Role/User semantics are not quite uniform across DB2, Oracle, Postgres and MySQL, for example -- and from this question I'm not even sure if you're asking about relational DBs or including all sort of others (many of these semantics don't even exist in Mnesia, for example).